# What does "derive with respect to $\arccos\left(x^2\right)$" mean?

Tags: derivatives

> Derive with respect to $\arccos\left(x^2\right)$ where
> $$f(x)=\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)$$

Can someone please explain to me what does "with respect to $\arccos\left(x^2\right)$" mean ?

Comment: By the chain rule,$$\frac{df}{d\arccos x^2}=\frac{dx}{d\arccos x^2}\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{\frac{df}{dx}}{\frac{d\arccos x^2}{dx}}$$for a differentiable function $f(x)$.

Comment: Assuming that you did not mean to say differentiate, and instead intended **derive**, it means that you let $\theta$ equal the angle such that $\cos(\theta) = x^2.$  Then, the assignment is to re-express $f(x)$ in terms of the variable $(\theta)$, rather than the variable $(x)$.  In other words, the assignment is asking you to construct the function $g(\theta)$ such that $g(\theta) = f(x).$

Comment: Re last comment, as a starting point, you have that $$\sqrt{1 + x^2} = \sqrt{1 + \cos(\theta)}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the question wants you to substitute $y=\arccos(x^2)$ and find $f(x)$ in terms of $y$.

So,

$$
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\arctan\left(
\frac{\sqrt{1+\cos y} - \sqrt{1-\cos y}}
{\sqrt{1+\cos y} + \sqrt{1-\cos y}}\right)\\
&=\arctan\left(
\frac{\cos(y/2) - \sin(y/2)}
{\cos(y/2) + \sin(y/2)}\right)\\
&=\arctan\left(
\frac{\cos(y/2+\pi/4)}
{\sin(y/2+\pi/4)}\right)\\
&=\arctan(\cot(y/2+\pi/4))\\
&=\arctan(\tan(\pi/4-y/2))\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{y}{2}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\arccos(x^2)}{2}
\end{align}
$$

Indeed [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=%5Carctan%5Cleft%5C%2840%29%5Cfrac%5C%28123%29%5Csqrt%5C%28123%291%2BPower%5Bx%2C2%5D%5C%28125%29-%5Csqrt%5C%28123%291-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5C%28125%29%5C%28125%29%5C%28123%29%5Csqrt%5C%28123%291%2BPower%5Bx%2C2%5D%5C%28125%29%2B%5Csqrt%5C%28123%291-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5C%28125%29%5C%28125%29%5Cright%5C%2841%29+%2BDivide%5B%5Carccos%5C%2840%29Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D-Divide%5B%5Cpi%2C4%5D) agrees (up to computational error).

Even if the question wants you to compute the derivative, it should be pretty easy from the last line above.

I used [half-angle formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Half-angle_formulae), [sum and difference identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities), and [reflection between cot and tan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Reflections).

Answer (score 1):

If you meant to say "Derivative", it means $$ \frac{df(x)}{d \arccos(x^{2})}. $$
Please see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4474543/significance-of-derivate-of-a-function-w-r-t-other-function).